# Drop-down Menu in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a drop-down menu in HTML/CSS, but I am not getting anywhere. I am trying to display the content `div` ONLY when the `Channel` `button` is being hovered on. I tried looking at w3schools, but it didn't help.

```css
.NavWrapper {
 background: grey;
 max-width: 5000px;
 min-width: 500px;
 height: 50px;
 align: center;
 padding: 10px;
}
.Home {
 border: 0;
 color: black;
 background: white;
 height: 50px;
 width: 80px;
}
.Channel {
 border: 0;
 color: black;
 background: white;
 height: 50px;
 width: 80px;
 transition-duration: 0.3s;
 position: relative;
}
.Content-Wrapper {
 background: grey;
 max-width: 5000px;
 min-width: 500px;
 height: 50px;
 align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 display: none;
}
.Channel:hover, .Content-Wrapper {
 background: silver;
 color: black;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class = "NavWrapper">
 <button class = "Home">
  Home
 </button>
 <button class = "Channel">
  Channel
 </button>
 <div class = "Content-Wrapper">
 <button class = "Content-Button">
  Hello World!
 </button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AgeDeO no, I just need help fixing a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.NavWrapper {
 background: grey;
 max-width: 5000px;
 min-width: 500px;
 height: 50px;
 align: center;
 padding: 10px;
}
.Home {
 border: 0;
 color: black;
 background: white;
 height: 50px;
 width: 80px;
}
.Channel {
 border: 0;
 color: black;
 background: white;
 height: 50px;
 width: 80px;
 transition-duration: 0.3s;
 position: relative;
}
.Content-Wrapper {
 background: grey;
 max-width: 5000px;
 min-width: 500px;
 height: 50px;
 align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 display: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.Channel:hover + .Content-Wrapper {
 background: silver;
 color: black;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class = "NavWrapper">
 <button class = "Home">
  Home
 </button>
 <button class = "Channel">
  Channel
 </button>
 <div class = "Content-Wrapper">
 <button class = "Content-Button">
  Hello World!
 </button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, now how can I create it neat, to where it displays under the NavWrapper?

Comment: Thanks Young Kyun Jin

Comment: @ChaseBarnes Check my answer. Do you want to make like that?

Comment: It will be useful later on, so if I need to, yes!

Comment: @ChaseBarnes Clear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155534/discussion-between-chase-barnes-and-young-kyun-jin).

Comment: Hey, can you edit the code to align it to the left, like the NavWrapper?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `.Channel:hover, .Content-Wrapper` to `.Channel:hover + .Content-Wrapper`.

Personally I would look at your markup and use ul's and li's to create what you're trying to do, but that at least fixes your display issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using `mouseover` and `mouseleave` events to `show` and `hide` the target. Here is the working example:

```js
$('.Channel').on('mouseover', function() {
  $('.Content-Wrapper').show()
})

$('.Channel').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $('.Content-Wrapper').hide()
})
```

```css
.NavWrapper {
 background: grey;
 max-width: 5000px;
 min-width: 500px;
 height: 50px;
 align: center;
 padding: 10px;
}
.Home {
 border: 0;
 color: black;
 background: white;
 height: 50px;
 width: 80px;
}
.Channel {
 border: 0;
 color: black;
 background: white;
 height: 50px;
 width: 80px;
 transition-duration: 0.3s;
 position: relative;
}
.Content-Wrapper {
 background: grey;
 max-width: 5000px;
 min-width: 500px;
 height: 50px;
 align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 display: none;
  background: silver;
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "NavWrapper">
 <button class = "Home">
  Home
 </button>
 <button class = "Channel">
  Channel
 </button>
 <div class = "Content-Wrapper">
 <button class = "Content-Button">
  Hello World!
 </button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is good, but I don't know how to use Javascript, and the other answers already beat you to it in CSS. I'll still upvote you though!

Comment: @ChaseBarnes, it's a matter of taste, what to use, JavaScript or pure CSS. In your case the CSS solution is more preferable, because you simply want to show/hide. You have to use JavaScript when you need more control and you goal is more complex. Thanks for the upvote!